# Do NaN-boxing and tagged pointers have a future on 64bit platforms?

Tags: pointers, language-agnostic, 64-bit, x86-64, arm64

On common 64bit architectures like x86-64 and arm64, usually only 48 bits are used for memory addressing, while the other bits are copies of bit 47 (which is usually zero for user-space programs). Thus, the remaining 16 bits can be used to store additional data like type tags etc., as long as those bits are masked off before dereferencing. Alternatively, the 48 bits can fit into the NaN-representation of a 64-bit float number. Both techniques are often used by dynamic/interpreted languages.

I've read about Intel 5-level-paging which would extend the address range from 48 to 57 bits, thus significantly reducing the leftover bits and also rendering NaN-boxing impossible. The Linux Kernel has already added support for this paging scheme.

Given that 48 bits correspond to 262,144 GiB of memory we can assume that we won't need the 57 bit range anytime soon on consumer devices like PCs, laptops and phones, and thus one might assume that on those devices we will remain on the 48 bit mode for a long time to come, with the above mentioned techniques remaining viable, while the 57 bit mode will be only used for servers/supercomputers.

Am I correct to make those assumptions? Or are there indicators that even consumer-scale devices will use the 57 bit mode in the near future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if memory-mapped persistent storage becomes widespread (NV-DIMM), it'll be a while before consumer PCs have more than 64TiB or 128TiB of storage + DRAM.  Remember that high-half kernels want half the virtual address space for kernel use, and typically want to direct-map all physical memory to a bit contiguous range of virtual addresses.  *As well* as making other mappings in kernel space, I think.  e.g. see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt for what Linux does.

As you suspect, OSes wouldn't actually enable PML5 on computers that have far less than 256TiB of physical address space.  There's no need for that much virtual address space and it has a performance cost (more expensive page-walks from another level of page tables).  The page-walk hardware wouldn't always be able to keep the two actually-used top-level entries cached; invalidations of everything on CR3 changes can force flushing.  (Page-walk hardware can in general cache upper levels of the radix tree to speed up TLB misses for nearby pages.)